# syntax error near unexpected token `do

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, syntax

I have a "syntax error near unexpected token `do" error, using a for loop in a .sh. Here is the code :

```
#!/bin/sh

# some code

for flux in $(ls -d /home/eai/*/*/*) ; do
  FICHIER=$(ls -p -tr $flux | grep -v / | head -n 1)
  if [[ $FICHIER ]] ; then
     # some code
  fi
done
```

## Different ways to execute the script, and the output :

1) sh script.sh or bash script.sh

```
'cript_1409.sh: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'cript_1409.sh: line 24: `for flux in $(ls -d /home/eai/*/*/*); do
```

2) ./script.sh

```
-bash: ./script_1409.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

## What I tried :

1) Use different syntax for the loop.

```
for flux in $(ls -d /home/eai/*/*/*) ; do
  FICHIER=$(ls -p -tr $flux | grep -v / | head -n 1)
  if [[ $FICHIER ]] ; then
     # some code
  fi
) &
done
```

or

```
for flux in $(ls -d /home/eai/*/*/*)
do
  FICHIER=$(ls -p -tr $flux | grep -v / | head -n 1)
    if [[ $FICHIER ]] ; then
      # some code
    fi
done
```

2) Change the #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash.

3) Change the extension .sh to .bash and retry all the execution commands aforementioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is `DOS` encoded and `sh` / `bash` do not like this.
Install `dos2unix` and run

```
dos2unix <script>
```

on your script. And run it again.